# Linking error when building Parse in Xcode 7

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9, xcode7, swift2

I am trying to add the Parse.com SDK to my Xcode 7 project. I have followed the getting started guide and I have managed to do it before in Xcode 6.
However this time I am being shown this error message when I try to build:

```
ld: framework not found Bolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `Bolts.framework` to the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`?

Comment: Yes.I have added it to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` and `Link Binary with Libraries`

Comment: Can anyone add an answer that doesnt involve cocoapods?  I am having the same issue but do not want to add Cocoapod dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you integrate Parse using CocoaPods.

Cocoapods manages the library dependencies in a much better way.

The following is a sample PodFile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

target '**YourProjectName**' do

  pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.1'

  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.3'

end
```

Comment: Is there any documentation to help with this? I have used Cocoapods for Google Analytics before. Do I create a file called Podfile?

Comment: Yes you need to create that file. Refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 if you face any dofficulty then feel free to ask me..

Comment: Should I simply write: `platform :ios, '9.0'` and `pod 'Parse'` or `pod 'Parse.com'`

Comment: If you would like to support iOS 9.0 users only then you can write 9.0 else you can write 7.0 or so. if you set 7.0 then majority of the users & devices will be covered. For the pod file content i have updated my answer with it. Please copy & paste it there you go. Remove AFNetworking stuff if you don't need it.

Answer (score 17):

There seems to be an issue with Xcode 7 beta where the search path for manually added frameworks is missing.

To fix the issue add the search path by doing the following:

1. Select Project
2. Click on Targets
3. Click Build Settings
4. Search for: Framework Search Path
5. Add the following without the quotes: "$(PROJECT_DIR)" and choose recursive option.

The project should build now.

Comment: Should this replace what is currently there or be added to it?

Comment: Totally unrelated topic, but might help for people trying to include Facebook SDK: Add `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` to the search paths as well.

Comment: @TomCoomer this should replace what is currently there.

Comment: Added the Directory but, not working for me. Is there any solution.