# ld: framework not found Parse Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7, xcode7-beta2

I succeed to install and use Parse framework with my new project, but I can't with a "template project".

The template is just a [Slide Menu](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) from [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com)

You can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax0zhk655j204zu/SidebarMenu.zip?dl=0).
I have this error :

```
ld: framework not found Parse
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And the same for Bolts.

I don't understand what the problem is, the initial project is just some View Controllers...

When I write the code "import Parse", the error message is :

```
No such module 'Parse'
```

I tried to drag and drop the frameworks, and also to add the frameworks in "Link Binary With Libraries".

PS : I am using Xcode 7 beta, and I tried on beta 1 and 2, same issue.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is the solution:

There seems to be an issue with Xcode 7 beta where the search path for manually added frameworks is missing.

To fix the issue add the search path by doing the following:

1. Select Project
2. Click on Targets
3. Click Build Settings
4. Search for: `Framework Search Path`
5. Add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and choose **Recursive** option.

The project should build now.

Thanks to this post : [Link to stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741206/linking-error-when-building-parse-in-xcode-7)

Comment: I am using my own framework and simply added it to the Project, but the search path was missing. This seems only to happen in the Beta right now. Hopefully this will be fixed again.
I also have to add the framework under General>Embedded Binaries by my self!

Comment: lol, this helped me. I actually don't know how it worked magically, but, anyway, it works.

Comment: it's 'Framework Search Path' not 'Frameworks Search Path'

Answer (score 7):

None of the proposed solutions worked for me. Eventually I found that the solution was to drag the frameworks from a source folder that did not have spaces in it's name.

E.g.

- Dragging the frameworks from 'iOS SDKS' > did not work
- Dragging the frameworks from 'Downloads' > worked

It's not the first time that XCode has been shown to be problematic when working with paths that contain spaces.

Comment: This worked for me as well!! Was desperately banging my head against solutions marked as accepted for long!

Comment: My framework name doesn't have space. Still it shows ' framework not found RWUIControls '

Comment: Thanks Keeth. your answer  helped me .

Comment: Same problem exists in the release version of Xcode 8 - doesn't add the search path automatically, so you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that Parse is included in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under "Build Phases".

Comment: Parse is included in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.
The same with Bolts.

Comment: included in the Link Binary library section.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Build Phases -> Linked Binary With Libraries remove your pod framework & add it back again. That does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same issue. In my case, somehow there were multiple frameworks added to the project, and one of the framework is empty. After removing the empty framwork it started compiling.

Comment: Hi, This cannot be considered as a complete answer. You can add it as a comment instead when you have enough reputation to :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you accidentally break your framework, e.g. if the framework contained an Alias, which is no longer there.

This can happen if you zip the file, as the Alias contains a direct link to the orignal file, and isnt updated when you move the zip.  E.g. in my case I recieved a zip of the opencv framework, and inside it had just the 'Versions' folder and no aliases to Headers, Resources or the binary.  You can just recreate the aliases, or compile the framework from source again.

This took a while to figure out!