# How to use opencv2.framework in ios correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

I have tried many times to use opencv in my ios project, but it just failed.
After I download the framework from the website, I load the framework to my xcode project, and then it just shows the following problem, I really don't know why and have been mad about it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check out this link. This should help you!

http://fyhao.com/2015/01/computer-and-it/tutorial/tutorial-on-setup-opencv-on-ios/

Best regards,
N. Medeiros

Comment: sorry, but I don't think this works for me. I think this is a problem of not loading the framework correctly. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295369/ld-framework-not-found-parse-xcode-7-beta  after reading the website link, I still can't solve this problem...