# ld: framework not found SystemConfiguration

Tags: ios, objective-c, ld

Whenever i try to build and run app in the real device i get this error
[image]

But not when i run the app in the simulator!

how to resolve this error?
I have tried

- project clean
- deleting derived data
- setting the framework path to recursive
  [image]

Comment: try to remove and add it again...and also please look for header search path.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295369/ld-framework-not-found-parse-xcode-7-beta/31298214#31298214) may be helpful!

Comment: i tried that but it is not working @RichardG