# How can I solve XCode 12 build error with Parse SDK?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, swift5

I just downloaded XCode 12.2 and created new empty project.
Then I imported Parse SDK with pod.
The problem is that the project doesn't build.

errors found:

#### framework not found Parse

> ld: framework not found Parse
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I solve it?

Comment: Likely duplicate of many existing questions with good answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295369/ld-framework-not-found-parse-xcode-7-beta

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue and tried a dozen different fixes. The one that seemingly worked was to update the Podfile to install Parse directly from GitHub.

I changed `pod 'Parse'` to `pod 'Parse', :git => 'https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git'`

I say "Seemingly" because some of my other fixes may have contributed to its success.

Answer (score -2):

Which version of the Parse SDK are you using? Can you share the contents of your Podfile?
Did you open the xcworkspace file instead of the xcodeproj?
I just installed Parse 1.18.0 using Cocoapods and it is working normally.