# Linking error Xcode 7.2: Framework Not Found

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, cocoapods

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for hours. Every time I try to build my project, I get the same error:

> ld: framework not found SwiftHTTP

I tried following the instructions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192971/2434726) but to no avail.

Are there any ideas as to what else I may be doing wrong?

Comment: so... has the framework been added to SwiftHTTP ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: the error is self-explained. the framework cannot be found. Either it's missing, or the path is mis-configured. Did you use Cocoapods to install it? It's available in Cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org/?q=SwiftHTTP

Comment: Yes, I used cocoapods to install the framework. A `SwiftHTTP` directory is in the `Pods` directory in my project, but I cannot find a `.framework` file anywhere

Comment: Last, did you open the `.xcworkspace` (instead of `.xcproject`)?

Comment: Yes, I was not opening the `.xcworkspace` but even once I did that, my project still is not building

Comment: Thank you for that. I had forgotten that Xcode needs to be open via .xcworkspace when dealing with cocoapods. The build was still failing because I had borked all of the paths already trying to deal with the failures. I simply re-cloned my repo and now everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, OP accessed the project via `.xcproject` instead of `.xcworkspace`, thus the framework is not loading. To solve the problem (and restore to recommended settings by Cocoapods), follow the steps below:

1. Close all Xcode project / workspace
2. In Terminal, issue `pod update` in the Project folder to restore the settings
3. After Cocoapods finished running, open the `.xcworkspace` and build the project